# Stress energy pseudotensor of the repulsive gravity of an exotic matter

Tags: general-relativity, mass, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Postulating the existence of a hypothetical negative mass, would the pseudotensor of its repulsive gravitational field have a negative stress energy? If so, why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it would, according to Gerard t'Hooft: "...it could have been that Newton’s constant G turned out to be negative. Gravity would be a repulsive force but that does not seem to contradict anything. Until you compute the energy of gravitational waves: that energy would have been negative, which would be somewhat disturbing from a physical point of view."

Source:
http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gravitating_misconceptions.html

Answer (score 0):

Relativists don't really talk about negative mass, they talk about [energy conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_condition). If you were going to talk about negative mass, you would have to specify carefully whether you meant inertial mass, active gravitational mass, or passive gravitational mass. Stress-energy is a tensor, not a scalar, so again, it doesn't really make sense to talk about it as positive or negative; we can talk about whether or not it violates certain energy conditions. You can talk about the Newtonian limit, where only the 00 component of the stress-energy is nonnegligible, but in the Newtonian theory, the gravitational field of a *positive* mass has *negative* energy density.

Comment: While I agree with what you're saying here, this should be a comment, not an answer post.

Comment: We could also talk about the local *eigenvalues* of the stress-energy tensor.